# Programmatically modifying timestamps of files on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

How can I programmatically modify the creation and lastmodified times of files in Sharepoint Online to times in the past?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint CSOM to achieve this，below is my demo for you:

```
        String name = "michael";
        String password = "Password";
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(name, securePassword);
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael");
        ctx.Credentials = credentials;
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Mylist");
        ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
        item["Created"] = "2020-01-01";
        item["Modified"] = "2020-01-01";
        item.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```